# Getting Type Error: GetDataRage is null? in google apps script for my google site

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a Google apps script that will allow me to use a Google sheet.  I would like the app to read the data on the sheet, and then output a table into my Google site.  I also want to be able to select which columns I want displayed on the Google site.  I cannot use Awesome Tables because my Google Drive has sensitive client information -- so I do not want to grant access to Awesome Table.  (My goal to create something like the "awesome table" People Directory without using that app).  I have been researching for the last two days - and I realize I probably have to write my own Google app script.  Problem is I'm not that proficient in JavaScript yet.  So, the code below is what I have come up with - but I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getDataRange" of null. (line 4, file "Code", project "App Script for Employee Page")

Also, I tried using Debugger -- to me it looks like it is creating an array with my data, but I can't see the problem.
Why is this not working?  Can anyone send me to where there is a template to help me read data off a Google sheet and display to my specifications (certain columns etc)?

```
function doGet(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSONString);
    JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return JSONOutput
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which spreadsheet you are accessing:
Like so:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Your Sheet ID here")
```

Then you will access the specific sheet/tab in your spreadsheet like so:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name of your Sheet");
```

Note you will have to substitute "Your Sheet ID here" and "Name of your Sheet" to your [sheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id) and sheet name respectively for the code to work. For more information on the function used above visit [google apps script reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Complete code below:

```
function doGet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Your Sheet ID here")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name of your Sheet");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSONString);
    JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return JSONOutput
   }
 }
```

Hope that helps